# hashCode(): Objects.hash() And Base Class?

Tags: java, hash, java-7, hashcode

Let's say I have two classes

```
class A {

  private String aStr;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(aStr);
  }

}
```

and

```
class B extends A {

  private String bStr;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(bStr);
  }

}
```

As the fields of class `A` are still fields in `B` that need to be hashed, how do I properly include the hash code of the fields in `A` in `B.hashCode()`? Any of these?

```
Objects.hash(bStr) + super.hashCode();
// these generate a StackOverflowError:
Objects.hash(bStr, (A) this);
Objects.hash(bStr, A.class.cast(this));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd probably use

```
Objects.hash(bStr, super.hashCode())
```

You definitely want to combine the state you know about with the superclass implementation of `hashCode()`, so any solution would want to use `bStr` and `super.hashCode()`... your original idea of addition would work too, of course - it's just a different way of combining the results.